# Change uploads to a different document library in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Is there a way to change the upload to a document library, so that the file gets uploaded to another library?

My requirements are: If a user uploads documents to library A it should instaed be uploaded to a hidden library B, there the file will be processed in some sort and then the processed file gets put in library A. The original file should not be in library A at any point, so processing the file after upload in library A is only a fallback option if there is no way to do this.

It only needs to work from the website. A method working for office uploads would be nice but isn't required.

Comment: Wouldn't be less complicated to upload to the doclib B which would be dedicated for uploading only and process the document with a workflow that at the end moves the document to the doclib A?

Comment: @FerdinandPrantl The requirements are that the user doesn't see doclib B.

Comment: I know that but I think that changing that requirement would make it easier and still comply with the main requirement - process the document before it gets accessible in the doclib A. Remember the *incoming* directory on FTP.

Comment: One more idea: Why not using the standard approval workflow to get a document published?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom action replacing the Upload ribbon button in the doclib A with your own pointing to your own ASPX page. This page would allow posting a file and whatever else you need. In the code behind you would create a new document in a doclib B with the content of the posted file. You could use a workflow or other means to process the document.

What remains unaddressed: multifile upload, Office upload, WebDAV upload. You could create another page for multifile processing but I can't imagine how to handle the latter two.

--- Ferda

Comment: I waited a few days if there would be any more answers. This is pretty much what I ended up doing. Perhaps I try the Workflowmethod from your comment later. Thanks.